# Интервал времени в dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraph

Как сделать так, чтобы время на графике от dygraph было так:

> 18:00:00 18:00:30 18:01:00 18:01:30

А не так, как сейчас:

```
18:00:00 18:00:02 18:00:04 18:00:06
```

http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update -> Edit in jsFiddle

Может кто работал с Dygraph и знает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, на какой оси у тебя время. Я подозреваю, что на X.

При создании графика, в конструктор ты передаешь JSON с параметрами (по-моеум последний параметр). Дак вот, добавь туда коллбэк, для формирования ярлычков для осей.

```
   axes: {
        x: {
              axisLabelFormatter: labelFormatter,
            },
        y: {
           }
    }
```

labelFormatter - это колбэк, который принимает на вход значения по оси X в местах, в которых dygraph хочет нарисовать метки. Далее, останется только поиграть с шагом сетки, наверняка есть какая-то настройка для этого. Либо просто попробовать вернуть null или undefined из labelFormatter, если ты не хочешь рисовать в данном месте метку.

Comment: FreeDooM, мне нужно как-то интервал увеличивать. Чтобы я видел на графике 18:00:00 18:00:30 18:01:00 18:01:30, а не 18:00:00 18:00:02 18:00:04 18:00:06.

Сам график http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update -> Edit in jsFiddle

Comment: Ты когда данные формируешь для графика, оборачиваешь значения для X в new Date(x) ? Dygraph собъектами типа Date как-то особенно работает. У тебя есть промежуточные значения по X? т.е. между 18:01:00 18:01:30 ? Если нет, то просто попробуй подпихнуть в конструктор нужные данные, с нужным интервалом.

Comment: FreeDooM, глянь, пожалуйста, всё как тут. http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update -> Edit in jsFiddle